# Watin Visible of Text

Tags: c#, watin, element, visible

I'm Using Watin tool in C# to find a text is available in webpage/URL. Using the code:

```
bool flag =  browser.containsText("Some Text");
```

But returns true, but the text("Some Text") is hidden in page.  I need to get only visible text of a URL. i Dont Have the ID/Name of the Element...

Comment: Can you post up html as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Find the control that is hidden and check to see if it is visible and contains the text.

Example if it were a Div and using NUnit:

```
Assert.IsTrue(myBrowser.Div.Style.GetAttributeValue("visibility") == "hidden" && myBrowser.Div("myPossiblyHiddenDiv").Text.Contains("the text"));
```

Lots of ways to check for the text; I usually try to go as granular as possible in case there are other controls on the page that contain the text in question.

Comment: i Dont have the id/name of the element...I have only Plain text.. I need to know the text is visible or not... Can u please help me.

Comment: There are lots of ways you can identify the entity that is visible/hidden.  If you don't have the ID nor the name, you could find the element containing the text then find the ancestor of that element that controls the visible/hidden state.  Or you could use the index of the element on the page (eg myBrowser.Divs[3].....)  ID is the usual best way to find the element, but there are other ways; if you post some sample HTML getting some very specific help will be a lot easier.